# Excel 2013 does not display default sheet after adding in C#

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

In Excel 2013 I can't add a Worksheet after creating the workbook. My C#-Program did this, but if I set the Application on Visible = true, there is no Worksheet in it. My Program can rename Sheets, copy Sheets, but can't Show me them.
After all is done in my program, it need to be saved, but it doesnt work, because there is nothing displayed what can be saved!

This is my code:

```
Excel.Application appversion = new Excel.Application();
appversion.Visible = true;

Excel.Workbook dataBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
dataSheet = dataBook.Worksheets[1]; // <- this sheet is not visible
dataSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible; // does not work
dataSheet.Name = Seiten[0]; // but my program continues
```

After adding the workbook Excel starts with this:

[workbook without sheet](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3838/7js2sdti_jpg.htm)

But where is the default sheet? Without that, I can't save anything. In Excel 2010 all Sheets I need appear and I can see how my program works.

Comment: First you use `appversion` and then `excelApp` as `Excel.Application`, probably typo.

Comment: omg! yes, you are right! I used 2 Excel.Applications and didn't saw them. That's the Problem with codes which I hadn't seen in months. Thx!